# xml string to file using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml

How i can make an xml file from NSString object?

In other words, how can I parse XML from an NSString object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for the iPhone, you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283774/saving-a-string-into-file-in-objective-c-iphone) which goes over doing it on the iPhone, using the user defaults method.

For reference, on Mac OS X one could use the [`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:) NSString Method.

**EDIT**: To parse the XML within an NSString, you can use the [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. This class does not have a method to initialize it with an `NSString`, so you have to use its [`initWithData:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/initWithData:) method like this:

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

And that will initialize it with the `NSString`'s data.

Of course, you have to learn how to parse the XML itself using this class. You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa) for some tips, or you can google around for some tutorials, such as Apple's very own [walkthrough](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html). Here is [another](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html) walkthrough for using the class.

Comment: Yes it is for iphone but i think you link the question wrong, can you relink the question, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's fixed :)

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible not to make any physical copy of file and take string as xml document and process it? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. My understanding was that you wanted to store XML that was in an NSString, in a file. So in other words, save the NSString into an .xml file. What is it you want to do exactly? Take an NSString and parse the XML?

Comment: Yes that's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the xml you're parsing is in plist format, you can use the handy-dandy [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class methods to parse it into a plist object for you.